# Minus (except) of 2 same queries return non-empty resultset

Tags: sql, oracle, except

I have a problem with the following SQL. Why on the earth minus of 2 exactly same queries would return non-empty result? I have tried "UNION ALL" instead of UNION, I have tried many other things, none of which worked. PLease advise.

```
    SELECT y.segment1 po_num, fad.seq_num seq, fdst.short_text st
              FROM applsys.fnd_attached_documents fad,
                   applsys.fnd_documents fd,
                   applsys.fnd_documents_short_text fdst,
                   po_headers_all y
             WHERE     1 = 1
                   AND fad.pk1_value(+) = y.po_header_id
                   AND fad.entity_name = 'PO_HEADERS'
                   AND fad.document_id = fd.document_id
                   AND fd.datatype_id = 1
                   and fad.seq_num>=100
                   AND fdst.media_id = fd.media_id
                   and y.type_lookup_code='STANDARD'
                   AND NVL(y.CANCEL_FLAG,'N')='N'
                 --  and y.segment1 in (100,1000,100,650,26268)
                --   and y.segment1=1000
            UNION 
            SELECT poh.segment1, 1, '1' --null, null
              FROM    po.po_headers_all poh
                   LEFT JOIN
                      (SELECT fad1.pk1_value
                         FROM applsys.fnd_attached_documents fad1,
                              applsys.fnd_documents fd1
                        WHERE     1 = 1
                              AND fad1.entity_name = 'PO_HEADERS'
                              AND fad1.document_id = fd1.document_id
                              and fad1.seq_num>=100
                              AND fd1.datatype_id = 1) sub1
                   ON poh.po_header_id = sub1.pk1_value
             WHERE sub1.pk1_value IS NULL 
                        and poh.type_lookup_code='STANDARD'
                        AND NVL(poh.CANCEL_FLAG,'N')='N'
                      --  and poh.segment1 in (100,1000,100,650,26268) 
                      --  and poh.segment1=1000                       
          --   and poh.segment1=650)              
          minus
   SELECT y.segment1 po_num, fad.seq_num seq, fdst.short_text st
              FROM applsys.fnd_attached_documents fad,
                   applsys.fnd_documents fd,
                   applsys.fnd_documents_short_text fdst,
                   po_headers_all y
             WHERE     1 = 1
                   AND fad.pk1_value(+) = y.po_header_id
                   AND fad.entity_name = 'PO_HEADERS'
                   AND fad.document_id = fd.document_id
                   AND fd.datatype_id = 1
                   and fad.seq_num>=100
                   AND fdst.media_id = fd.media_id
                   and y.type_lookup_code='STANDARD'
                   AND NVL(y.CANCEL_FLAG,'N')='N'
                   --and y.segment1 in (100,1000,100,650,26268)
                   --and y.segment1=1000
            UNION 
            SELECT poh.segment1, 1, '1'--null,null
              FROM    po.po_headers_all poh
                   LEFT JOIN
                      (SELECT fad1.pk1_value
                         FROM applsys.fnd_attached_documents fad1,
                              applsys.fnd_documents fd1
                        WHERE     1 = 1
                              AND fad1.entity_name = 'PO_HEADERS'
                              AND fad1.document_id = fd1.document_id
                              and fad1.seq_num>=100
                              AND fd1.datatype_id = 1) sub1
                   ON poh.po_header_id = sub1.pk1_value
             WHERE sub1.pk1_value IS NULL 
                        and poh.type_lookup_code='STANDARD'
                        AND NVL(poh.CANCEL_FLAG,'N')='N'
                      --  and poh.segment1 in (100,1000,100,650,26268)
                      --  and poh.segment1=1000
                      --   and poh.segment1=650)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parentheses. Right now, you're doing `((set1 UNION set2) MINUS set1) UNION set2` while you meant to do `(set1 UNION set2) MINUS (set1 UNION set2)`.

In other words, you're uniting set1 and set2, removing set1 from that and uniting set2 with that, while you probably meant to take a union of set1 and set2 and remove a union of set1 and set2 from that. `UNION` and `MINUS` have the same precedence and are processed in the order they're encountered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, firstly, you do a UNION of the first two queries, then, you do a MINUS of the third and then you UNION the result with the fourth query.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `UNION [ALL]` and `MINUS` have the same priority. Essentially, if we ignore the details, you're doing:

```
SELECT query1
UNION
SELECT query2
MINUS
SELECT query1
UNION
SELECT query2
```

Since all these set operators have the same priority, they evaluate one by one. 
`SELECT query1 MINUS SELECT query2 UNION SELECT query1` should return `query2`. Then, the last `UNION` is applied, and the result is `SELECT query2 UNION SELECT query2`, which is of course `query2`.

To resolves this, you'd have to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT query1
               UNION
               SELECT query2)
MINUS
SELECT * FROM (SELECT query1
               UNION
               SELECT query2)
```